# Using mod_rewrite to search for file or directory in different, non-contiguous, folders

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a set of mod_rewrite rules to search a series of paths for a file or directory;
if the "thing" is not found on the first path, then try the 2nd, 3rd, etc  I've
found other examples online, but they all seemed to have a very simple tree structure,
such as path/dir1 path/dir2 path/dir3, where they add or replace a single element
in the path.  The path structure I need to traverse is not so simple, and beyond my control to change.

So 'thing' - which could be a directory or a discrete file - could be in any number of places

```
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/this/is/the/first/path/thing
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/a/second/path/emerges/thing
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/then/there/is/a/third/path/thing
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/omg/we/have/another/path/to/look/at/thing
```

Here's the most successful attempt so far; I have this in the virtualhost section

```
RewriteEngine On
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8

# default pass-through case
RewriteCond   %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule   (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 [L]

# I tried adding this rule
RewriteCond   %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/a/second/path/emerges/thing/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule  (.*)/this/is/the/first/path/thing(.*) $1//a/second/path/emerges/thing/$2 [L]
```

But the RewriteCond concatenates the first path onto the 2nd path, which of course isn't found eg /a/second/path/emerges//this/is/the/first/path/

I know that %{REQUEST_FILENAME} contains the entire filesystem path and REQUEST_URI contains the path
without DOCUMENT_ROOT.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to create a RewriteCond statement with a string
where "/this/is/the/first/path/thing" is replaced by "/a/second/path/emerges/thing" for the condtion.
In sed I'd do something ike s%/this/is/the/first/path/thing%a/second/path/emerges/thing%g but I don't know how, or if there is a way,
to do this as part of a RewriteCond statement.  My logic here is to test if the file exists on the subsequent path,
and if so, rewrite the URL and stop processing the rules

I tried writing a rule using the negative condition for the 2nd rule, eg

```
RewriteCond   %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteRule  (.*)/this/is/the/first/path/thing(.*) $1//a/second/path/emerges/thing/$2 [L]
```

And it sort of worked, but there were a lot of unexpected side effects, such as when I tried to browse the 1st directory,
I was always redirected to the 2nd directory, and could never get back to the first one.

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to scrap this plan and attack it in a completely different manner?

Comment: So you want to make changes in a already existing htaccess file? By using `sed` you want to change some text in it? Please confirm on same.

Comment: No, I was merely using the sed statement as an example of what I would want the RewriteCond to look like.